# axios.spread() cache my API whereas axios.get() does not

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm facing a weird situation where I need to call a bunch of my CMS API routes from my server in order to use their `response.data` into an object that will then be passed to my client side.

This is the code that caches my data: meaning that when I change a field on my CMS, that data that is being pulled is not updated.

The code is:

```
let baseUrl = "https://sismographie-cms.herokuapp.com/api/"
let locales = ["?locale=en", "?locale=fr"]

let links = [
  "contact-page",
  "keywords",
  "podcasts",
  "random-question-arrays",
  "featured-entries-headlines-anims",
  "main-text",
  "headline",
  "cookie-setting",
  "header-info-array",
  "random-question-prompt",
  "contact-page",
  "map-entry-right-text",
  "map-entry-left-text",
  "sponsor-logos",
  "credit",
  "projects-about-texts"
  ].map((ele, index) => {
  return {
    en: `${baseUrl + ele + locales[0]}`,
    fr: `${baseUrl + ele + locales[1]}`,
  }
});


let objectKeys = [
  "info",
  "keywords",
  "podcasts",
  "randomQuestions",
  "featuredEntries",
  "balladosSubtitle",
  "balladosTitles",
  "cookiesSetting",
  "headerInfoArray",
  "randomQuestionPrompt",
  "conctactPage",
  "mapEntryRightText",
  "mapEntryLeftText",
  "sponsorLogos",
  "credit",
  "ProjectsAboutText"
];


let getAxiosRequests = (locale) => {
  return links
  .map((ele, index) =>  {
    return axios.get(ele[locale])
  })
};



axios.all(getAxiosRequests("fr"))
.then(axios.spread((...responses) => {

  let cmsObjFr = mapToObject(objectKeys, responses);
  
  axios.all(getAxiosRequests("en"))
  .then(axios.spread(
    (...responses) => {
    let cmsObjEn = mapToObject(objectKeys, responses);
    console.log(cmsObjEn);
    app.get('/cms-routes', (req, res) => {
      res.json({fr: cmsObjFr, en: cmsObjEn})
    })
  })).catch(errors => {
    console.error(errors);
  });
})).catch(errors => {
  console.error(errors);
});

 const mapToObject = (objectKeys, responses) => { 
    return objectKeys.reduce( 
        (sum, key, index) => Object.assign(
        sum, { [key]: responses[index].data.data}),{} 
    ); 
 };
```

When I access the `json` object, I see that the field I just changed did not update.

When I individually call that same field's CMS route, however, the response contains the updated version of the data:

```
app.get("/credits", (req, res ) => {
  console.log("/credits' call");
  axios.get("https://sismographie-cms.herokuapp.com/api/credit?locale=en")
    .then(data => res.json(data.data))
})
```

For, let's say, the credit field, this method will give me the updated version I don't have access when I'm using the `axios.spread` method.

Comment: `axios.all()` and `axios.spread()` are deprecated. Use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that because you create your route handler (`app.get("/cms-routes")`) after retrieving data, the data it responds with is fixed and will never change.

You need to move the data retrieval logic *into* the route handler.

Also, as mentioned above `axios.all()` and `axios.spread()` are deprecated and should not be used.

```js
const links = {
  info: "contact-page",
  keywords: "keywords",
  podcasts: "podcasts",
  randomQuestions: "random-question-arrays",
  featuredEntries: "featured-entries-headlines-anims",
  balladosSubtitle: "main-text",
  balladosTitles: "headline",
  cookiesSetting: "cookie-setting",
  headerInfoArray: "header-info-array",
  randomQuestionPrompt: "random-question-prompt",
  conctactPage: "contact-page",
  mapEntryRightText: "map-entry-right-text",
  mapEntryLeftText: "map-entry-left-text",
  sponsorLogos: "sponsor-logos",
  credit: "credit",
  ProjectsAboutText: "projects-about-texts",
};

const baseURL = "https://sismographie-cms.herokuapp.com/api/";

/**
 * Resolves with an array of single property objects, eg
 * [
 *   {
 *     info: {...}
 *   },
 *   {
 *     keywords: {...}
 *   },
 *   ...
 * ]
 */
const getAll = (locale) =>
  Promise.all(
    Object.entries(links).map(async ([key, link]) => ({
      [key]: (await axios.get(link, { baseURL, params: { locale } })).data.data,
    }))
  );

app.get("/cms-routes", async (req, res) => {
  const [fr, en] = await Promise.all([getAll("fr"), getAll("en")]);

  res.json({ fr: Object.assign(...fr), en: Object.assign(...en) });
});
```

I've taken the liberty of simplifying your data structures so your links and object keys are tightly coupled.